# Spring application deployed to WebLogic - <fast-swap> set to true - org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, weblogic12c

The application works fine without this added to the `weblogic.xml`

```
<fast-swap>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</fast-swap>
```

---

Here is their documentation for using `<fast-swap>`

[Using FastSwap Deployment to Minimize Redeployment](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/DEPGD/deployunits.htm#DEPGD153)

---

Here is the entire error

```
   [[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fleetSeriesHelpRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property beaInvoke found for type FleetSeriesHelp!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
```

Answer (score 0):

Evidently WebLogic's fast-swap has limited support for reflection - which Spring uses everywhere.

https://zeroturnaround.com/forums/topic/javarebel-vs-fastswap/